# Why Am I Getting The Incorrect Levenshtein Distance?

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance

I am attempting to implement the Levenshtein Distance algorithm in C# (for practice and because it'd be handy to have).  I used an implementation from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) but for some reason I'm getting the wrong distance on one set of words.  Here's the code (from LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
   var ld = new LevenshteinDistance();
   int dist = ld.LevenshteinDistanceCalc("sitting","kitten");
   dist.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class LevenshteinDistance
{
   private int[,] distance;

   public int LevenshteinDistanceCalc(string source, string target)
   {
      int sourceSize = source.Length, targetSize = target.Length;
      distance = new int[sourceSize, targetSize];
      for (int sIndex = 0; sIndex < sourceSize; sIndex++)
      {
         distance[sIndex, 0] = sIndex;
      }
      for (int tIndex = 0; tIndex < targetSize; tIndex++)
      {
         distance[0,tIndex] = tIndex;
      }
      //      for j from 1 to n:
      //      for i from 1 to m:
      //          if s[i] = t[j]:
      //            substitutionCost:= 0
      //          else:
      //            substitutionCost:= 1
      //          d[i, j] := minimum(d[i - 1, j] + 1,                   // deletion
      //                             d[i, j - 1] + 1,                   // insertion
      //                             d[i - 1, j - 1] + substitutionCost)  // substitution
      //
      //
      //      return d[m, n]

      for (int tIndex = 1; tIndex < targetSize; tIndex++)
      {
         for (int sIndex = 1; sIndex < sourceSize; sIndex++)
         {
            int substitutionCost = source[sIndex] == target[tIndex] ? 0 : 1;
            int deletion = distance[sIndex-1, tIndex]+1;
            int insertion = distance[sIndex,tIndex-1]+1;
            int substitution = distance[sIndex-1, tIndex-1] + substitutionCost;

            distance[sIndex, tIndex] = leastOfThree(deletion, insertion, substitution);

         }
      }
      return distance[sourceSize-1,targetSize-1];
   }

   private int leastOfThree(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      return Math.Min(a,(Math.Min(b,c)));
   }
}
```

When I try "sitting" and "kitten" I get an LD of 2 (should be 3).  Yet when I try "Saturday" and "Sunday" I get an LD of 3 (which is correct).  I know something's wrong but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: This is because you're starting the loops from 1 rather than 0 - you will see you get the correct result whenever the inputs start with the same letter - 'cat' vs 'cog' correctly returns 2, 'cat' vs 'dog' incorrectly returns 2.

Comment: Onorio, do you must implement it this way, because im thinking of a more easy soluton in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example on wikipedia uses 1-based strings. In C# we use 0-based strings.

In their matrix the 0-row and 0-column does exist. So the size of their matrix is [source.Length + 1, source.Length + 1] In your code it doesn't exist.

```
public int LevenshteinDistanceCalc(string source, string target)
{
  int sourceSize = source.Length, targetSize = target.Length;
  distance = new int[sourceSize + 1, targetSize + 1];
  for (int sIndex = 1; sIndex <= sourceSize; sIndex++)
    distance[sIndex, 0] = sIndex;

  for (int tIndex = 1; tIndex <= targetSize; tIndex++)
    distance[0, tIndex] = tIndex;

  for (int tIndex = 1; tIndex <= targetSize; tIndex++)
  {
    for (int sIndex = 1; sIndex <= sourceSize; sIndex++)
    {
      int substitutionCost = source[sIndex-1] == target[tIndex-1] ? 0 : 1;
      int deletion = distance[sIndex - 1, tIndex] + 1;
      int insertion = distance[sIndex, tIndex - 1] + 1;
      int substitution = distance[sIndex - 1, tIndex - 1] + substitutionCost;

      distance[sIndex, tIndex] = leastOfThree(deletion, insertion, substitution);
    }
  }
  return distance[sourceSize, targetSize];
}
```

Comment: I had noticed the 0 based vs. 1 based in Wikipedia but I guess I just didn't consider all the potential problems that could cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix isn't big enough.

In the pseudo-code, `s` and `t` have lengths `m` and `n` respectively (`char s[1..m], char t[1..n]`). The matrix however has dimentions `[0..m, 0..n]` - i.e. one more than the length of the strings in each direction. You can see this in the tables below the pseudo-code.

So the matrix for "sitting" and "kitten" is 7x8, but your matrix is only 6x7.

You're also indexing into the strings incorrectly, because the strings in the pseudo-code are 1-indexed, but C#'s strings are 0-indexed.

After fixing these, you get this code, which works with "sitting" and "kitten":

```
public static class LevenshteinDistance
{
    public static int LevenshteinDistanceCalc(string source, string target)
    {
        int sourceSize = source.Length + 1, targetSize = target.Length + 1;
        int[,] distance = new int[sourceSize, targetSize];
        for (int sIndex = 0; sIndex < sourceSize; sIndex++)
        {
            distance[sIndex, 0] = sIndex;
        }
        for (int tIndex = 0; tIndex < targetSize; tIndex++)
        {
            distance[0, tIndex] = tIndex;
        }
        //      for j from 1 to n:
        //      for i from 1 to m:
        //          if s[i] = t[j]:
        //            substitutionCost:= 0
        //          else:
        //            substitutionCost:= 1
        //          d[i, j] := minimum(d[i - 1, j] + 1,                   // deletion
        //                             d[i, j - 1] + 1,                   // insertion
        //                             d[i - 1, j - 1] + substitutionCost)  // substitution
        //
        //
        //      return d[m, n]

        for (int tIndex = 1; tIndex < targetSize; tIndex++)
        {
            for (int sIndex = 1; sIndex < sourceSize; sIndex++)
            {
                int substitutionCost = source[sIndex - 1] == target[tIndex - 1] ? 0 : 1;
                int deletion = distance[sIndex - 1, tIndex] + 1;
                int insertion = distance[sIndex, tIndex - 1] + 1;
                int substitution = distance[sIndex - 1, tIndex - 1] + substitutionCost;

                distance[sIndex, tIndex] = leastOfThree(deletion, insertion, substitution);
            }
        }
        return distance[sourceSize - 1, targetSize - 1];
    }

    private static int leastOfThree(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return Math.Min(a, (Math.Min(b, c)));
    }
}
```

(I also took the liberty of making `distance` a local variable since there's no need for it to be a field (it only makes your class non-threadsafe), and also making it static to avoid the unnecessary instantiation).

To debug this, I put a breakpoint on `return distance[sourceSize - 1, targetSize - 1]` and compared `distance` to the table on Wikipedia. It was very obvious that it was too small.

Comment: That's a great point about distance not needing to be a field.